# Freemember with EE 3?

Tags: freemember

I was wondering if anyone was using or had tested Freemember with the new EE 3.x ? I'm working on upgrading some sites and I used this in a few of them. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Freemember has not been updated to be compatible with EE3 - you'd have to contact DevDemon and ask if they have plans. (It doesn't appear in their [EE3 roadmap](http://www.devdemon.com/blog/expressionengine-3.0-porting), and as a free add-on that was Adrian's baby before he sold Expresso Dev to DevDemon, it may not happen.)

But it's open source, so anyone can tackle the conversion ad make a pull request.

Comment: Bummer I like the add on for its simplicity (in use/functionality) - I'd have to look to see if it would be worth re-coding for EE3 Thanks!

Comment: FreeMember for EE 3 will be available very soon on DevDemon!

Comment: Any news on that front? Haven't been able to find a version for EE3 yet.

Comment: Hi guys any news on the EE3 version ?  Or any work arounds

Comment: Guess this never happened, is freemember for EE4 likely?